Some code analysis IDE* rules stops build only in buld server but not on local machine
I have .editorconfig file for example with this one rule
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0018.severity = error

I have Directory.Build.props with
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup>

    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>

    <!--
    <AnalysisLevel>latest</AnalysisLevel>
    <AnalysisMode>All</AnalysisMode>
    <ReportAnalyzer>true</ReportAnalyzer>
    <Features>strict</Features>
    <EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
    <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>true</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>
    <RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>true</RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>
    -->

    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
    <CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>true</CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>

    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>

    <AccelerateBuildsInVisualStudio>true</AccelerateBuildsInVisualStudio>

  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>


Yes, analysis is commented for now, but I want to treat warnings as errors.
When I try to build project, all works fine. No error is thrown. But when build starts in Azure DevOps on build server (Build Tools installed on build agent), it fails as
##[error]xxx.cs(92,9): Error IDE0018: Variable declaration can be inlined

Build are using msbuild task. Application is .Net Framework 4.7.2.
It happens for some IDE* rules, but some other rules raises in local machive. For example IDE0017 is ok and stops build on dev machine.
My question is - why it happens? Why some rules stops build on local machine and some are ignored but raises on build server?
Other rules that fails only on build server: IDE0018, IDE0019, IDE0020, IDE0029, IDE0030, IDE0031, IDE0034, IDE0270, ...

Are your local and CI environments using different versions of the .NET SDK? It might be that there's different versions of the rule assemblies in the two locations, creating the disparate behaviour.

Major version is the same. Local machine has .Net 8.0.202 + VS 17.9.5 and build server has .Net 8.0.101 and Build Tools 17.8.0. There should be no difference. Tried to run on my pc exact msbuild command as in log in build server and no error.

Maybe you're seeing this issue where the 8.0.2xx SDK isn't reporting errors it should: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/39742

hmm, nice, I'll check older SDK

@MartinCostello Verified. Problem is in 8.0.2xx. 8.0.1xx works fine. Thnx for help
